# Django tutorial setting the correct path variable

Tags: python, django, windows

I am having trouble with the tutorial, I am stuck here `django-admin.py startproject mysite`
In the shell I get an error `django-admin.py Command no found`

I believe I have set the correct path variables?  Here is what I have done in the shell:

First I typed in  `$ python`

from there python booted up and I got the `>>>`
so I typed `import django` and then `django.get_version()` and everything works
and I see `1.4.2`

Next I exited python and tried to set up the test site from the tutorial.

```
$ django-admin.py startproject mysite
```

I get the same error.

```
django-admin.py Command no found
```

Where am I going wrong?  Do I need to set the path for django as well?

Thanks for your help I tried to be as descriptive as possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you don't have `django-admin.py` in your path.

A guide to solving it is outlined on the [Django installation pitfalls](https://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/InstallationPitfalls) page:

> #### SYMPTOM
>
> ```
> -bash: django-admin.py: command not found
> ```
>
> #### PROBABLE CAUSE
>
> You don't have django-admin.py on your command search PATH.
>
> #### SOLUTION
>
> Link /bin/django-admin.py to whereever on your PATH.
>
> Note that Python on most unix-like system uses `/usr/local/lib/python2.X/site-packages/` for 3rd-party packages:
>
> ```
> sudo ln -s /usr/local/lib/python2.4/site-packages/django/bin/django-admin.py /usr/local/bin/django-admin.py
> ```
>
> However, Python 2.6 uses `/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/` for 3rd-party packages:
>
> ```
> sudo ln -s /usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/bin/django-admin.py /usr/local/bin/django-admin.py
> ```
>
> You may get a "permission denied" message after this. To change the permissions of the django-admin.py file to be executable do:
>
> ```
> sudo chmod +x /usr/local/bin/django-admin.py
> ```
>
> If you've installed Python 2.6 and made it the default version, you may have to use django-admin-2.6.py startproject mysite instead.

Mind you, this may not be sufficient if `/usr/local/bin` isn't in your path. You can check your path easily in your terminal:

```
$ echo $PATH
/home/sebbe/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games
```

If `/usr/local/bin` isn't in your path, you need to add that as well. See [Add folder to PATH](https://superuser.com/q/251038/5407) for an explanation of how to do that.

Comment: Oh sorry I am using windows; just using the GIT Gui program.  I am also using Python 3.3.

Comment: @spitfiredd: Do you mean Git Bash? If so, try following the steps anyhow. You may need to substitute python2.4 for python3.3, but it should be similar.

Comment: @spitfiredd: The problem the shell is giving you means, that `django-admin.py` isn't in your path. That has nothing to do with your Python version. Try writing `python --version` to see what version of Django you run by writing `python`. That's the version you have Django installed for.